# Pulling div data using “simple html parser”

Tags: php

Hey So what I am trying to do is scrape a site, and pull all the info from each div and put it into an array.

```
<div id ="quote-header-info">
   <div>Info I want in array</div>
   <div>More Info I want in array</div>
   <div>Some more Info I want in array</div>
   <div>even more Info I want in array</div>
</div>
```

I am able to pull all of the data into my page, but it keeps all of the div formatting and i cant modify the divs attributes.

Right now I have

```
function ScrapeDiv ($url, 'div[id=quote-header-info]', $dNum) {
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    foreach ($divScrape->find('div') as $child){
        $divData[] = $child->innertext;
    }
PrintArray($divData);
```

}

this pulls all data that I want, but includes the div tags in the array and seems to duplicate each div as well.

This is what Im trying to achieve

```
array
   (
    [0]=>Info I want in array
    [1]=>More Info I want in array
    [2]=>Some more Info I want in array
    [3]=>even more Info I want in array
   )
```

Comment: I think I figured it out, issue was using innertext instead of plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

For querying data in XML/HTML XPath is way to go.

Your case:

```
<?php
$html = '<div id ="quote-header-info">
    <div>Info I want in array</div>
    <div>More Info I want in array</div>
    <div>Some more Info I want in array</div>
    <div>even more Info I want in array</div>
</div>';

// Load HTML data 
$xml = new DOMDocument();

// You may want to suppress error messages to avoid HTML parsing related warnings
@$xml->loadHTML($html); 

// Initialize XPath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

// Query -> give me text of all div nodes inside 
// div node with id attribute = quote-header-info 
$items = $xpath->query("//div[@id='quote-header-info']/div/text()");

// Result is traversable already, but let's translate it into an array
$result = [];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $result[] = $item->wholeText;
}

print_r($result);
```

[More about XPath at w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp),
[PHP XPath Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)